# Repeated Fieldの内容を順番通りに表示したい

Tags: google-bigquery

App EngineのLogをStreaming InsertでBigQueryにExportしています。

Application LogはprotoPayload.line.logMessageにRepeatedFieldとして格納されているのですが、以下のクエリではRepeatedFieldの順番が失われてしまいます。
Application Logの順番が狂うと、中身が追いにくいので、RepeatedFieldの順番のままに表示したいのですが、何か良い手はないでしょうか？

```
SELECT insertId, protoPayload.resource, protoPayload.taskQueueName, protoPayload.startTime, protoPayload.endTime, protoPayload.line.logMessage 
FROM [dataset.table] 
WHERE (protoPayload.status / 100) = 5
ORDER BY insertId, protoPayload.startTime, protoPayload.endTime
LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position Functionを利用すれば、repeated fieldの添字を取れるため、順番通りに表示できることが分かりました！

```
SELECT insertId, protoPayload.resource, protoPayload.taskQueueName, protoPayload.startTime, protoPayload.endTime, protoPayload.line.time, POSITION(protoPayload.line.logMessage) AS logPosition, protoPayload.line.logMessage 
FROM [dataset.table] 
WHERE (protoPayload.status / 100) = 5
ORDER BY insertId, logPosition, protoPayload.startTime, protoPayload.endTime
LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

App EngineのLogであれば、protoPayload.line.timeの昇順に並べれば、ひとまず見たい内容にはできました！

```
SELECT insertId, protoPayload.resource, protoPayload.taskQueueName, protoPayload.startTime, protoPayload.endTime, protoPayload.line.time, protoPayload.line.logMessage 
FROM [dataset.table] 
WHERE (protoPayload.status / 100) = 5
ORDER BY insertId, protoPayload.startTime, protoPayload.endTime, protoPayload.line.time
LIMIT 1000
```

ただ、これはRepeated Fieldの順番通りに表示しているわけではないので、引き続き有識者の回答をお待ちしております！